# Bearing (or angle) of spatial line at given distance along line

Tags: r

working in R, let's say I have got a spatial (poly)line `myline` (which is in fact a road section in The Netherlands)

**sample data**

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
myline <- new("SpatialLinesDataFrame", data = structure(list(WVK_ID = 276318044, 
    WVK_BEGDAT = structure(18017, class = "Date"), JTE_ID_BEG = 276318271, 
    JTE_ID_END = 277319114, WEGBEHSRT = "R", WEGNUMMER = "027", 
    WEGDEELLTR = "R", HECTO_LTTR = "#", BST_CODE = "HR", RPE_CODE = "R", 
    ADMRICHTNG = "H", RIJRICHTNG = "H", STT_NAAM = "Rijksweg A27", 
    STT_BRON = "BAG schrijfwijze", WPSNAAM = "Groenekan", GME_ID = 310L, 
    GME_NAAM = "De Bilt", HNRSTRLNKS = "N", HNRSTRRHTS = "N", 
    E_HNR_LNKS = NA_integer_, E_HNR_RHTS = NA_integer_, L_HNR_LNKS = NA_integer_, 
    L_HNR_RHTS = NA_integer_, BEGAFSTAND = 0L, ENDAFSTAND = 777L, 
    BEGINKM = 83.607, EINDKM = 84.395, POS_TV_WOL = "R", WEGBEHCODE = "137", 
    WEGBEHNAAM = "MN District Zuid", DISTRCODE = 137L, DISTRNAAM = "MN District Zuid", 
    DIENSTCODE = "MN", DIENSTNAAM = "RWS Midden-Nederland", WEGTYPE = "HW", 
    WGTYPE_OMS = "Hoofdweg", ROUTELTR = "A", ROUTENR = 27L, ROUTELTR2 = NA_character_, 
    ROUTENR2 = NA_integer_, ROUTELTR3 = NA_character_, ROUTENR3 = NA_integer_, 
    ROUTELTR4 = NA_character_, ROUTENR4 = NA_integer_, WEGNR_AW = "RW27", 
    WEGNR_HMP = "A27", GEOBRON_ID = 30L, GEOBRON_NM = "Kaart Mutatiebeheerder (grafisch verantwoord)", 
    BRONJAAR = 2019L, OPENLR = "CwOo2CUQSAEADQEVAqIBEQ==", WPSNAAMNEN = "GROENEKAN"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    lines = list(new("Lines", Lines = list(new("Line", coords = structure(c(5.14622136332401, 
    5.14628006055521, 5.14644706285959, 5.14653002049188, 5.14664954917351, 
    5.1468225003734, 5.14693777078116, 5.1471111136675, 5.14731318164235, 
    5.14739992808142, 5.14796341038545, 5.14834481638318, 5.1484162733709, 
    5.14898651452541, 52.1206777197773, 52.1213637132524, 52.1220713169937, 
    52.1225081015583, 52.1228672105364, 52.1232899995222, 52.1235778506305, 
    52.123928735863, 52.1243695593071, 52.1245315197956, 52.1256561645874, 
    52.1263383000577, 52.1264661103159, 52.1274140196899), .Dim = c(14L, 
    2L)))), ID = "1")), bbox = structure(c(5.14622136332401, 
    52.1206777197773, 5.14898651452541, 52.1274140196899), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

and I have a point `mypoint`, which is a gantry located 233 metres (=29,98713% of total length) along `myline`. The point is found by

```
mypoint <- rgeos::gInterpolate(myline, 0.2998713, normalized = TRUE)
# class       : SpatialPoints 
# features    : 1 
# extent      : 5.146639, 5.146639, 52.12284, 52.12284  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

plotted with leaflet, this looks like (line = blue, point = red):

[image]

**what I want to achieve**
I want to get coordinates from points offset 100-200-300-400 metres from `mypoint`, perpendicular to `myline`. I already found the function for this; `geoshere::destPoint()`. But the problem is that I am not able to calculate the angle/bearing this function needs.

**my question**
I need to calculate the bearing/angle of the polyline `myline` on the location of `mypoint`. Or, more general, I want to find the bearing/angle of a polyline at a given distance along this polyline (in this example 233 metres alomng the line, or at 29.98716% of it's total length).

I tried this by cutting up the polyline to individual segments, find which segment is located at 233 metres 'in', and then calculate it's angle based on the start/end coordinates of this segment. While this seems to result in the answer I need, it is slow and it feels like a clumsy approach. I am sure/hoping better methods/functions are available in the sf/rgeos/geoshere/...?... packages. I just cannot seem to find them.

Comment: The spatialEco package has a function `bearing.distance` that calculates a new point based on an input bearing/distance. You should be able to backwards engineer the source code to give you what you want. I would lend a hand with adapting the function but, am currently far too busy. Here is the source: https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco/blob/master/R/bearing.distance.R

Comment: thanks Jeffrey, (but) that functionality sounds exacltly like `geosphere::destPoint()` mentioned in the question. However, in order to use this function (and/or spatialEco::bearing.distance, I need a bearing at the startpoint. Which is exaclty what I am trying to get hold of.

Comment: For geographic coordinates have you tried something along the lines of: `atan2( sin(x2 - x1) * cos(y2), cos(y1) * sin(y2) - sin(y1) * cos(y2) * cos(x2 - x1) )`